# Como obtener registros del año corriente [RubyOnRails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

buenos días. Estoy intentando obtener los registros de una tabla 'Authorisations' correspondientes al año actual hasta la fecha de hoy. he podido obtener los del año pasado de la siguiente manera mediante un scope:

```
scope :año_pasado, -> {where("(id_cmp is null OR id_tipo_cmp = 7) AND state = ? AND created_at > ?", 'approved', 1.year.ago).length}
```

Utilice **1.year.ago** para obtener lo del año pasado, pero existe algo similar para obtener lo del año corriente?
Muchas gracias, desde ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `beginning_of_year`, lo que te va a dar el primer día del año basado en una fecha; por ejemplo:

```
Date.today
#=> Tue, 15 Sep 2020

Date.today.beginning_of_year
#=> Wed, 01 Jan 2020
```

Para obtener la información del año corriente, lo podrías utilizar en un `scope` de la siguiente manera:

```
scope :actual, -> { where("created_at >= ?", Date.today.beginning_of_year) }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Gerry ! Lo solucione de una manera muy similar, pero utilizando ese metodo.